# Jos Stam's stable fluids — why multiply by the grid size when subtracting out the curl-free part?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Considering page 10 of [Jos Stam's GDC tutorial](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/nsp/course/15-464/Fall09/papers/StamFluidforGames.pdf) on stable fluids, the function `project()` first obtains the divergence of the velocity field: ¹

```
div[IX(i,j)] = -0.5*(u[IX(i+1,j)]-u[IX(i-1,j)]+
                     v[IX(i,j+1)]-v[IX(i,j-1)]) / N;
p[IX(i,j)] = 0;
```

then subtracts a curl-free part from the original velocity field, to obtain a velocity field cleared of divergence:

```
u[IX(i,j)] -= 0.5*(p[IX(i+1,j)]-p[IX(i-1,j)]) * N;
v[IX(i,j)] -= 0.5*(p[IX(i,j+1)]-p[IX(i,j-1)]) * N;
```

This generally makes sense to me, except for one thing: I understand roughly why the first code block *divides* by `N` -- the calculation of divergence on a regular grid using finite differences involves dividing by the distance between the neighbouring grid cells. But why does the second code block *multiply* by `N`? I thought that the calculation of the gradient on a uniform grid would involve dividing by `N` as well, just as the calculation of the divergence does.

---

¹ For readability, in the below code blocks, I've replaced the reciprocal `h = 1.0/N` that's used in the implementation in this paper.

Comment: The new velocity is updated with pressure *gradient*, so the finite difference produces the $/(2*h)$ part, which equals to $0.5*N$, assuming the domain has unit size.

The divergence part should also have $/(2 *h)$. I am not sure about that part yet.

Comment: Indeed, that's the question. Whatever the scaling is, I'd expect the gradient and the divergence to have the same denominator, and yet they don't.

Comment: Oh I think I see it. The equation is div grad p = div u. Then on lhs there is a 1/dx^2 term, multiply through then the rhs gets a dx. You can verify it from how it solves with GS.

Comment: 1/(2dx)^2 actually if you are using colocated grid. That is also why there is a 1/4 in the GS iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the divergence computation:
The Poisson equation we are going to solve is
$$ \nabla \cdot \nabla p = \nabla \cdot u_{old}.$$
This is given by taking divergence on both sides of the conservation equation and $\nabla \cdot u_{new}=0$ since we assume the result velocity field should be divergence free.

Then discretize both sides on colocated grid:
$$\frac{p_{i+1,j}+p_{i-1,j}+p_{i,j+1}+p_{i,j-1}-4 p_{i,j}}{h^2} = \frac{u_{i+1,j}-u_{i-1,j}+u_{i,j+1}-u_{i,j-1}}{2 h}$$

Multiply $h^2$ through both sides
$$p_{i+1,j}+p_{i-1,j}+p_{i,j+1}+p_{i,j-1}-4 p_{i,j}= (u_{i+1,j}-u_{i-1,j}+u_{i,j+1}-u_{i,j-1}) \frac{h}{2}$$

That is why you get that $h/2=0.5/N$ factor in computing divergence (i.e. the rhs).

For the velocity update part, the new velocity is updated with pressure gradient, then the finite difference gives you the $1/(2h) = 0.5 N$ factor.